# How do I find the name of a player(s) within a certain area?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make a PvP mini-game and I'm trying to make it so that when a certain amount of players are left, it awards the players inside of the arena.

I have already managed to make the player counter for the area using some command blocks and a comparator, but I only know how to find the amount of players with `testfor`, not the actual names of the players.

How can I find the names of the players inside the arena?

Comment: What's your current `/testfor` command? You should just be able to use the selector from that in your `/give` commands.

Comment: yah i didnt know i could do that b4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power a repeat command block with this command:

```
/testfor @a[x=X,y=Y,z=Z,r=R]
```

Where `X`, `Y`, `Z` are the middle coordinates of the arena, R is the radius of the arena. Now, put this command in a repeating command block:

```
/testforblock X2 Y2 Z2 minecraft:command_block -1 {SuccessCount:SC}
```

Where `X2`, `Y2`, `Z2` are the coordinates of the 1st command block and `SC` is the amount of players you want to be left to award them.

Next to the 2nd command block place a chain command block with this command (or another if you don't want to give items, but be sure to use the `@a[x=X,y=Y,z=Z,r=R]`):

```
/give @a[x=X,y=Y,z=Z,r=R] minecraft:THE_AWARD_YOU_WANT
```

Where `X`, `Y`, `Z` are the middle coordinates of the arena.